# Find an expression for the first term in the asymptotic expansion

Tags: integration, analysis, asymptotics

How do I find the first term in the asymptotic expansion of the following.

$$\int_0^1 e^{-x(t^4+1)}\sin(t) \ dt$$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Attempt:

First replace $\sin(t)=t$ (Taylor series expansion - only need first term).

Therefore we have $e^{x}\int_0^1 e^{-xt^4}t \ dt $.

I am not sure on how to finish the steps - do we replace $e^{-xt^4}$ by it's Taylor series as well and then integrate term by term?

Comment: Try writing $\sin(x)=x+O\!\left(x^3\right)$

Comment: I have written an answer, but unless there is more context provided, it would not be in the best interests of the site, as explained in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959), to post the answer.

Comment: @robjohn would I write sin(t) as it's taylor series as you have suggested and then integrate term by term?

Comment: Yes, but for the first order, all you need is $t+O\!\left(t^3\right)$.

Comment: If you provide some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), I can post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1e^{-x(t^4+1)}\sin(t)\mathrm{d}t
&=e^{-x}\int_0^1e^{-xt^4}\sin(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=e^{-x}\int_0^1e^{-xt^4}\left(t+O\!\left(t^3\right)\right)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac14e^{-x}\int_0^1e^{-xt}\left(t^{-1/2}+O\!\left(1\right)\right)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac14e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{-t}\left(x^{-1/2}t^{-1/2}+x^{-1}O(1)\right)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac14x^{-1/2}e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{-t}t^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}t+\frac14x^{-1}e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{-t}O(1)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}4x^{-1/2}e^{-x}+O\!\left(x^{-1}e^{-x}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$